# Download specific classes from NTU RGB+D and 120 dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, dataset

I currently wish to download from the NTU-RGB+D-120, http://rose1.ntu.edu.sg/Datasets/actionRecognition.asp
only A50 to A120, Mutual Actions / Two Person Interactions (26) portion.
I do have access pass to download, however the sheer size and the other classes which I will not be using are making me question which download link will hit the right set containing A50-A120. Any responses will be helpful.